# How to turn remote xml file into string in Flutter?

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

There is a `.xml` file that I want to turn into/read as `String` in order to then parse it as `XML`.

How can I achieve that in Flutter?

**ex. xml file: https://www.cbar.az/currencies/16.03.2020.xml**

Comment: Did you try making an http get request to that url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Dart [xml library](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) can parse such files. There is an [example](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml/blob/master/example/ip_api.dart) included that downloads and parses IP address metadata, very similar to your example file. The [tutorial](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml#tutorial) contains further examples of how to read files:

```dart
final file = new File('bookshelf.xml');
final document = XmlDocument.parse(file.readAsStringSync());
```

Or download data:

```dart
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();
final url = Uri.parse('http://ip-api.com/xml/');
final request = await httpClient.getUrl(url);
final response = await request.close();
final stream = response
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(const XmlEventDecoder())
    .transform(const XmlNormalizer())
    .expand((events) => events)
    .forEach((event) => print(event));
```